# What do we mean when we write SCSI(0,0,0)?

Tags: filesystems, partition

I came across this when I was trying to install a new operating system and the partition manager in the disk showed me all the partitions. This was with a corresponding partion which already existed...

Answer (score 2):

It can vary from OS to OS but in general it means controller 0, disk 0, partition 0 - i.e. the first disk controller, the first disk on that controller and the first partition on that disk.